# Variable that is NOT empty saying undefined variable

Tags: php, mysql, phpexcel

Please check out the below code.

```
        $key = $_SESSION['order_nums'];
        $sqll = "SELECT * FROM `money` WHERE `order` = :key";
        $qq=$con->prepare($sqll);
        $qq->bindvalue(":key", $key);
        $qq->execute();


        $excel2 = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createReader('Excel2007');
        $excel2 = $excel2->load('nTest.xlsx'); // Empty Sheet
        $excel2->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
        $worksheet = $excel2->getActiveSheet();

        $Cno = '7';
        $COno = '7';
        $MSno = '7';
        $CHno = '7';
        $ALno = '7';


        while($fdata=$qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {   

                $totalCost += $fdata['cost'];


                /*
            $worksheet
                ->setCellValue('A' . $Cno++, $fdata['code'])
                ->setCellValue('D' . $COno++, $fdata['cost'])
                ->setCellValue('E' . $MSno++, $fdata['time'])
                ->setCellValue('F' . $CHno++, $fdata['hourly'])
                ->setCellValue('G' . $ALno++, $fdata['ot']);*/




        }
```

Ok, so the part of the code where it says `$totalCost += $fdata['cost']` is saying its a undefined variable. Yet the code below it that I commented out.. If I uncomment it, it works perfect.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you didn't define `$totalCost` variable before using it, so you should define it outside while loop `$totalCost = 0;`

```
$totalCost = 0;
while($fdata=$qq->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC))
        {   

                $totalCost += $fdata['cost'];


                /*
            $worksheet
                ->setCellValue('A' . $Cno++, $fdata['code'])
                ->setCellValue('D' . $COno++, $fdata['cost'])
                ->setCellValue('E' . $MSno++, $fdata['time'])
                ->setCellValue('F' . $CHno++, $fdata['hourly'])
                ->setCellValue('G' . $ALno++, $fdata['ot']);*/




        }
```

because this line `$totalCost += $fdata['cost'];` means `$totalCost = $totalCost  + $fdata['cost'];` and in this case it didn't find the var `$totalCost`

Comment: Jesus, I gotta stop missing the simple things. Thanks.

Comment: Correct. You can assign a value to a variable, but the addition operator will throw the warning.